# How to transpose rows into columns and it will become only one row?

Tags: sql, pivot-table, transpose

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MAX(D.RECEIVEDDATE) AS DATE,
    A.LOCATIONNUMBER AS ID_NAME,
    (SELECT CARRIERNUMBER FROM CARRIER C WHERE C.CARRIERID = D.CARRIERID) AS CR_NAME,
    D.DEPOSITREFERENCE As ITEM_REF,
    DC.CONTAINERNUMBER As ITEM_NUM,
    Z.DENOMINATION As Category,
    D.RECEIVEDCONTAINERS as ITEM_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z.DENOMINATION LIKE '%50%' THEN CAST(Z.VERIFIEDQUANTITY AS BIGINT) END) QTY_50_PCS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z.DENOMINATION LIKE '%100%' THEN CAST(Z.VERIFIEDQUANTITY AS BIGINT) END) QTY_100_PCS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z.DENOMINATION LIKE '%50%' THEN CAST(Z.VERIFIEDAMOUNT AS BIGINT) END) AMT_50_PCS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z.DENOMINATION LIKE '%100%' THEN CAST(Z.VERIFIEDAMOUNT AS BIGINT) END) AMT_100_PCS,
    CAST(D.VERIFIEDAMOUNT AS BIGINT) AS TOTAL_AMT
FROM
    DEPOSIT D
JOIN 
    ACCOUNT A ON D.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID 
LEFT JOIN  
    DEPOSITCONTAINER DC ON DC.DEPOSITID = D.DEPOSITID
LEFT JOIN 
    DEPOSITCONTAINERITEM Z ON Z.DEPOSITCONTAINERID = DC.DEPOSITCONTAINERID
LEFT JOIN 
    DEPOSITCONTAINERITEMUNIT X ON X.DEPOSITCONTAINERITEMID = Z.DEPOSITCONTAINERITEMID
WHERE 
    D.DEPOSITTYPE = 0 
    AND LOCATIONNUMBER LIKE 'Z%' 
    AND D.RECEIVEDDATE IS NOT NULL 
    AND Z.DENOMINATION IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    D.RECEIVEDDATE, A.LOCATIONNUMBER, D.CARRIERID, D.DEPOSITREFERENCE,
    D.RECEIVEDCONTAINERS, D.VERIFIEDAMOUNT, DC.CONTAINERNUMBER, DC.VERIFIEDAMOUNT, Z.DENOMINATION 
ORDER BY  
    D.DEPOSITREFERENCE
```

The output/result will become like this:

| DATE | ID_NAME | CR_NAME | ITEM_REF | ITEM_NUM | CATEGORY | ITEM_QTY | QTY_50_PCS | QTY_100_PCS | AMT_50_PCS | AMT_100_PCS | TOTAL_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-050-210001 | 50000 | 6 | 2000 | NULL | 100000000 | NULL | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-050-210002 | 50000 | 6 | 2095 | NULL | 104750000 | NULL | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-100-2100002 | 100000 | 6 | NULL | 2120 | NULL | 212000000 | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-100-210001 | 100000 | 6 | NULL | 2069 | NULL | 206900000 | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-RJC-210001 | 100000 | 6 | NULL | 383 | NULL | 38300000 | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-26 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | N5-RJC-210001 | 50000 | 6 | 213 | NULL | 10650000 | NULL | 672600000 |
| 2021-07-27 | CCY57 | CAB | 0344416011204ZZY57 | G6-50-210153 | 50000 | 6 | 68 | NULL | 3400000 | NULL | 140050000 |
| 2021-07-27 | CCY57 | CAB | 0344416011204ZZY57 | G6-50-210154 | 50000 | 6 | 75 | NULL | 3750000 | NULL | 140050000 |
| 2021-07-27 | CCY57 | CAB | 0344416011204ZZY57 | G6-RJC-210153 | 100000 | 6 | NULL | 486 | NULL | 48600000 | 140050000 |
| 2021-07-27 | CCY57 | CAB | 0344416011204ZZY57 | G6-RJC-210153 | 50000 | 6 | 26 | NULL | 1300000 | NULL | 140050000 |

How to get the transpose table with only one row and the columns based on the ITEM_NUM? For example, the 1st item **N5-050-210001** with value quantity of **2000** will be in the **QTY_50** column, then if there's second item **N5-050-210002** with value **2095**, it will be placed in second column **QTY_50_2**. This is also applied to the ITEM_NUM like '%-100-%' and '%-RJC%', the ITEM_NUM and Category columns will be eliminated and the result I want is to be like this:

| DATE | ID_NAME | CR_NAME | ITEM_REF | ITEM_QTY | QTY_50 | QTY_50_2 | QTC_RJC_50 | QTY_100 | QTY_100_2 | QTC_RJC_100 | AMT_50_PCS | AMT_100_PCS | TOTAL_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/26/2021 | XXN8A | ABC | 0039546898202ZZN8A | 6 | 2000 | 2095 | 213 | 2069 | 2120 | 383 | 215400000 | 457200000 | 672600000 |
| 7/27/2021 | CCY57 | CAB | 0344416011204ZZY57 | 6 | 68 | 75 | 26 | 773 | 57 | 486 | 8450000 | 131600000 | 140050000 |

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is (rarely) never needed when you do `GROUP BY`, because the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: Side note: Using a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is almost always a sign of a flaw; the `GROUP BY` is already forcing your data to be returned in *distinct* groups. This normally means your `GROUP BY` is wrong (which I would likely suggest it is, as there are more columns in your `GROUP BY` than there are unaggregated columns in your `SELECT`). Perhaps if you fix your `GROUP BY` (and remove the `DISTINCT` as it's just unneeded overhead) the problem will go away?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: `LEFT JOIN Z` combined with `where z.column is not null`, means that you actually want a regular `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, but could you give me suggestions on how to make each value in the ITEM_NUM to be transposed into columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result set that has a single row for each combination of `DATE`, `ID_NAME`, `CR_NAME`, and `ITEM_REF`, then these should be the only columns in the `GROUP BY`.  However, `DATE` is really an aggregation expression, so you only want the other three.

So:

```
SELECT MAX(RECEIVEDDATE) as DATE, ID_NAME, CR_NAME, ITEM_REF,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Z.DENOMINATION LIKE '%50%' THEN CAST(Z.VERIFIEDQUANTITY AS BIGINT) END) as QTY_50_PCS,
       .  .
FROM . . .
GROUP BY ID_NAME, CR_NAME, ITEM_REF;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my issue actually is how to distinguish values from the ITEM_NUM column which has almost similar value for example: 'N5-050-210001' and 'N5-050-2100002' so i can place them into different columns.